# How to use validates_uniqueness_of with ActiveModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I'm using ActiveModel to make my tableless models feel like ActiveRecord models. I'm using a custom store and I need to be able to validate uniqueness of a record.

How can I implement the required uniqueness check using ActiveModel?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
class Theme < Base

  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :id, :name
  validate      :uniqueness_of_theme_name, :on => :create

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    attrs.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def uniqueness_of_theme_name
    errors.add(:name, "name is already in use") unless Theme.find_by_name(name).nil?
  end

  def self.find_by_name(name)
    return store.find({ 'name' => "/^#{name}$/i" }).any?
  end

  def self.create(attributes = {})
    theme = Theme.new(attributes)
    theme.save

    return theme
  end

  def persisted?
    id && !id.nil?
  end

  def save()
    # only call validation during create context
    context = persisted? :update : :create
    false if invalid?(context)
    store.save(self)
    true
  end

  def self.create(attrs = {})
    theme = Theme.new(attrs)
    theme.save
    theme
  end

end
```

Maybe someone can tell me if this was the correct way to go about it

Comment: I cant understand, where are you storing this themes, so it can be validated as unique,

Comment: @RodrigoZurek, My store is actually mongodb. I've updated the code above. It's not complete but it should give you a better idea.

Comment: what includes of your **Base** class?

Comment: The base class includes some basic code that lets models interact with  mongodb

Answer (score -1):

Check this railscasts, it might help

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

once you do your model, add the validations and then @model.valid?

Comment: I know that tutorial is about table less models but it doesn't have any examples of uniqueness checks.

Answer (score -1):

ActiveModel can be used with according to another [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model), which is more suitable for that use-case.

```
class Theme

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  validates :name, uniqueness: true, on: :create

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: @mikhailob, based on what does the above code check the uniqueness of `:name`? I think validating uniqueness is a especial situation where it's correctness heavily relies on there being a data store and could not have been abstracted into the ActiveModel which doesn't require tables at all.

Comment: @Arman ActiveModel validation does happen once you call **save** (or explicit **valid?** method) on the Ruby object before any attempts to save data into MongoDB (or whatever you want). ActiveModel is an abstraction can help you to use plain object like ActiveRecord table-behind model.